# How to pass multiple parameters in array_walk

Tags: php, array-walk

I want to use array_walk so I am passing extra two array as parameter but didn't get exact process to deal it? o how to pass extra parameters in the form of array and access inside array_walk

```
 $main_array;
 $array_1;
 $array_2;

 array_walk($main_array, function(&$a, &$key) use($a, &$array_1, &$array_2) {
                            echo $a." :: ". $key."<br>";
                        });
```

Error:

```
Severity: Compile Error

Message: Cannot use lexical variable $a as a parameter name
```

Comment: `use($a, &$array_1, &$array_2)`?

Comment: @u_mulder getting error  ' Cannot use lexical variable $a as a parameter name '

Comment: You have `$a` both in parameters and in `use` How can php tell what is what?